# Some queries on viruses

Tags: vaccination, disease, virus

I'm someone from an Engineering background, so these questions might seem stupid, but I'd be grateful if someone could answer them.

1) How do viruses 'die'? Do they even die? I read that viruses are not even alive? If so what eventually happens to them?

2) Why is '14 days' of quarantine recommended for corona? Why 14? Why not 7 or 21 or a month?

3)  If someone gets cured of corona, does it mean that his cells have a 'memory' of combating the diseases in the future? Does it mean that a survivor is now resistant to the disease? (I think this is how vaccines work)

4) Why are people recommending to avoid chicken/fish/meat during this pandemic?

Thanks

Comment: Answer to #4: I don't know why they're saying such stupid things.

Comment: To 1), it depends on where they might be found. For example, I asked a question [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/23275/how-can-i-clean-my-papers-from-someones-coughs/) where the answer basically say that they don't live at high temperatures. 4) Idk but at first people were saying that the disease came from bats, and they were saying to stop eating bats soup or bat dishes, in general.